# Session_Start Event not firing daily for the first user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function written inside session start event for sending mails.For the first user of the day it sends mail and makes a falg=true in database.The next time for the new user or the same user it checks for the flag, if its true It doesnt send mails.This is how i want the function to perform.In simple words i want my web app to send a mail daily if i am the first user in current date. But i think its not firing everyday.If it fires everyday and my function is working fine then i should get mail everyday.I get mails after 2 or 3 days. Why so ? Should the function be written in session start itself? Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

session start event:-

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender,Eventargs e)
{
  try
  {
      //code to check if flag is true for todays date
      if(flag != true)
     {
      //get data from database and sent it in mail.
      //insert flag=true for current date
     }
  }
  catch()
  {
  }
```

}

Comment: C# is case-sensitive, also the method signature is wrong. Look in global.asax.cs what you need to use.

Comment: i have written the right method signature in my code.This is just to tell what i have written inside the start event

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["MyTest"] = "Your Data";
}
```

I think this code will work.

Are you sure that your global.asax file is hooked up to your application?

What happens when you add, say, a method to the global.asax, call that method from a ASPX page and then set a break point in the code. Does it break?

Use the same code given above because C# is Case Sensitive.

Thank you

Jom George

Comment: Do u want me to put my data in session which i want to send in email? The content of mails are coming properly.  yes my global.asax file is hooked up to my application.i place a breakpoint on my session_start event and debug my app.Even before the first page that is login page displays control goes to start event i debug my code.every thing seems to work fine on my local machine.mails are also received.But when i publish it on iis its not working properly.

Comment: I have checked all of it .everything looks ok.But no success.